# Is it possible to update the look and feel of the Microsoft Entra External ID authentication UX programmatically?

Tags: microsoft-entra-external-id

Is it possible to update the look and feel of the Microsoft Entra External ID authentication UX programmatically using automation? For example, rendering a new background image on daily/weekly or monthly basis?

If so, how could I accomplish this?

The documentation for the new Microsoft Entra External ID experience service offering mentions that it is possible to update the branding, but it is unclear from the guide whether this can be done programmatically like it can be done for previous service offerings. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/customers/overview-customers-ciam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with MS Graph API for Azure AD company branding. Please, make sure that App permission was granted to the application calling MS Graph API as it's described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organizationalbranding-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http.